# Comparing INT to long STRING

Tags: php, string, int

```
$test1 = (0 == "0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001");
$test2 = (0 == "0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001");

var_dump($test1); //Returns False
var_dump($test2); //Returns True
```

We are using PHP7 and we noticed this. We got to this point because we previously tried the following:

```
$test3 = (0 == "0"); //Returns true
$test4 = (0 == "1"); //Returns false
$test5 = (0 == null); //Returns true
```

So we started playing around with the variables.

**The first question** is: why does `$test1` return `false` while `$test2` returns `true`? Does this have to do with the floating point precision? Or is it some other tweak in the `php.ini` that controlls the length of the `string`?

**PD:** While this doesn't affect our real use case scenario, we are thinking on forcing ourselves to always use `===` instead of `==` to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: Cast your strings to float and see the difference.

Comment: Enable strict_types if possible and always use ===